# error term in the Taylor expansion of 1/x

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

What is the error in the Taylor polynomial of degree 5 for $f(x)=1/x$ using $x_0=3/4$ for $x\in [1/2, 1]$?

Since the $(n+1)th$ derivative of $f(x)=1/x$ is $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}{x^{n+2}}$, I think the remainder term would be

$R_{6}(x)=\frac{1}{\xi^{7}}(x-3/4)^{6}$. (is this correct?)

Now how many terms must be taken to get an error of less than $10^{-2}? 10^{-4}$? This one I am not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that $R_6(x) = \frac1{\xi^7}(x-3/4)^6$, where $\xi$ is a real number between $3/4$ and $x$. Now,
\begin{align}
\sup_{x,\xi\in[3/4,1]}|R_6(x)| &= \sup_{x,\xi\in[1/2,3/4]}\frac1{\xi^7}|x-3/4|^6\\ &= \frac1{(3/4)^7}(1-3/4)^6\\ &= \left(\frac 43\right)^7\left(\frac14\right)^6\\ &= \frac 4{3^7}\\ &= \frac 4{2187}\approx 0.001828989.
\end{align}
In general, 
$$
\sup_{x,\xi\in[3/4,1]}|R_{n+1}(x)| = \frac 4{3^{n+2}}.
$$
So to get the remainder less than $10^{-4}$ we have
$$
\frac 4{3^{n+2}} < 10^{-4}\iff n > \frac1{\log 3}(\log 40000 - \log 9)\approx 7.645473.
$$
Hence we need $n\geqslant 8$.

Comment: wouldn't the largest error be when $\xi = 1/2$? I thought the error should be $2^{n+2}\frac{1}{4}^{n+1}$